# Stack smashing detected during bitwise operation

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, stack-smash

I am trying to know the state of bits(0 or 1), using bit-wise operator,I am getting the desired output but along with that I'm getting this error of stack smashing detected. Please help me with this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char lights[2];
    int n;
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter byte %d\n",i);
        scanf(" %d",&lights[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++)
    {
        n=i/8;
        if(n==0)
        {
            if (lights[n] & 128>>i)
            printf("Light %d is on\n",i);
            else
            printf("Light %d is off\n",i);
        }
        if(n==1)
        {
            if (lights[n] & 128>>(i-8))
            printf("Light %d is on\n",i);
            else
            printf("Light %d is off\n",i);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is weird. The program runs without problems when compiled with clang, but not with gcc, but I have no explanation. Unrelated but you should probably change the for loop to run 16 times `for(i=0;i<16;i++)` .

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are trying to read a variable declared as `char` using the `%d` format in `scanf` (which will write an `int` to the address given):

```
scanf(" %d", &lights[i]); // lights is declared as char[2]
```

You should use the 'very small' size specifier in the format string ([scanf format specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)):

```
scanf(" %hhd", &lights[i]);
```

Not sure why this would give a "stack smashing" warning, but I'm not familiar with your code analyser, though (but see comment by **Alain Merigot**). However, trying to write an `int` value (probably 4 bytes) to a location that is only a `char` (1 byte) will be Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: As light[2] is put on the stack (just after rbp), writing an int to it clobbers rbp and create the stack smash... But I really wonder why this does not happen with clang.

Comment: @AlainMerigot I suspected that was the case but wasn't sure. On the clang issue, when I compile the original code with `clang-cl` (Visual Studio 2019), I get this: `warning : format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]`

Answer (score 0):

stack smashing is occurring as you are writing beyond the allocated stack, by writing char as an integer.

In higher version of GCC compiler it includes stack canaries which are protection code for stack overflow, you can disable this by -fno-stack-limit, then you will see segmentation fault.

The solution to the problem is the same as suggested by @Adrian